# how can I use networkx to find a node with a distance of 2 from the source node?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Is there an efficient function/method(because the graph is large) in networkx to identify all node which is 2 from the source node. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that your graph is `G` and your source node is `source`, then you can use [single_source_dijkstra_path_length](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path_length.html) to get path lengths as follows:

```
>>> source_path_lengths = networkx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G, source)
>>> for (v, l) in source_path_lengths.iteritems():
       if l == 2:
           print v
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This method is good but it may do not suitable for calculating the whole graph's node.This method needs to calculate other distance like 3 and 4, which are not use and waste time. Is there an efficient way that does not waste these time. thanks in advance.

Comment: @SunWJ You can always use the keyword argument `cutoff` to lower the search to paths smaller or equal to 2. Also, depending on your graph being weighted or not you can use `single_source_shortest_path_length` (non weighted).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can assign the 'cutoff' parameter as '2' as can be seen from the documentation for [Single Source Shortest Path - Networkx](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path.html). So basically algorithm finds the path till the length of the path <= cutoff .

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)

path = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G ,source=src_vertex,cutoff=2)
```

You could then use the following to the list of vertices at a distance of <=2 from source

```
print path.keys()
#output : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or you could print the dictionary itself to get exactly the distance between the source and the vertices upto length<=cutoff

```
print vertex_list
#Output : {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

You can change the value of 'cutoff' accordingly as per your need.